# Am I correct regarding this boolean method?

Tags: java, return

I was looking up how to perfect the movement in Java. The code I found looked like:

```
public void update() {
        
    for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNT_KEYS; i++) {
        keysLast[i] = keys[i];  ////Sets buttons pressed this frame equal to the lastKey array
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNT_BUTTONS; i++) {
        buttonsLast[i] = buttons[i];    //Sets buttons pressed this frame equal to the lastKey array
    }
}
    
//keys Methods
public boolean isKeyPressed(int keycode) {
    return keys[keycode];
}
    
public boolean isKeyUp(int keycode) {
    return !keys[keycode] && keysLast[keycode]; //Does not return 2 values, it returns true if these conditions are met?
}

public boolean isKeyDown(int keycode) {
    return keys[keycode] && !keysLast[keycode];
}
```

I was wondering if my thought regarding this snippet is correct, my guess is commented next to it:

```
public boolean isKeyUp(int keycode) {
    return !keys[keycode] && keysLast[keycode];  //Does not return 2 values, it returns true if these conditions are met?
}

public boolean isKeyDown(int keycode) {
    return keys[keycode] && !keysLast[keycode];
}
```

It seems to my eye that methods `isKeyDown` and `isKeyUp` return 2 booleans. I thought that was impossible. But I tested it and it seems like it acts like an **if-statement?**. So if the statement after the return command is true it will return true?

*Am I correct? If so why does it act that way? *

Comment: Look up boolean logic and the logical AND operator

Comment: Didn't know you could do it that way, seems a bit harsh to downvote because I didnt have the knowledge. I'll look it up

Comment: I wasn't the downvote, and you asked for a doc to read about it so I obliged

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to point at you Tyler, sorry! I just don't like downvotes, it's tough to get rep so I mixed it into that comment. I looked it up and understand now. It's a neat feature actually! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, does your code compile? The following would only be valid if your arrays returned a `boolean` value.

```
return !keys[keycode] && keysLast[keycode];
```

And if keys[keyCode] is true then !keys[KeyCode] would be false and the statement would return false since the rest of the expression need not be evaluated.

Comment: It compiles. So in the isKeyUp method it returns " !keys[keycode] && keysLast[keycode]" as you said. So if the key is up this frame and was down last frame it would return true on both . Due to the "!", if the "!" didnt exist it would return false && true. I get how it works, I just didn't know you could write it like this

Comment: so when you return a boolean you can make statements?

Comment: Yes.  `If(a && b)` is the same as `boolean result  = a && b;  if(result)`

Comment: Thats a neat feature actually...  how have I missed this :/

Comment: Well, it isn't necessarily that intuitive.  Also remember that `&&` is short circuiting and `&` is not.    For `a && b`  b will not be evaluated if `a` is `false`.  But for `a & b` , `b` **will** be evaluated regardless of `a`.

Comment: Didn't know that existed either! I'll accept your answer as the question has been answered in the comments! Thanks